# Surprising approximate identity

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

While answering this MO question [Connection between Bernoulli numbers and Riemann-Siegel theta function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/218993/connection-between-bernoulli-numbers-and-riemann-siegel-theta-function) Dan Romik
found the following surprising approximate identity:
$$\ln{8\pi}\approx \pi\left[ 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2/3}-\frac{1}{2}\right].$$
It is surprising because the relative accuracy is about $1.6\cdot 10^{-8}$ and I think it deserves a separate question: is this result just an isolated accident or something more profound is lurking behind it?

Comment: As a point of comparison, the closest approximation that the Inverse Symbolic Calculator gives for $\ln 8\pi$ is $(\sqrt[4]{7})(\sqrt[3]{3})(\sqrt{17})/3$, which is slightly worse than the right-hand side above.  The ISC also suggests 70000/21711 as a good approximation.